# Androids getTextBounds()

Tags: android

Just a quick one - what is the advantage in defining the function as

```
public void getTextBounds (String text, int start, int end, Rect bounds)
```

where the result is returned in `bounds`, rather than just having

```
public Rect getTextBounds (String text, int start, int end)
```

Presumably this has been done for a specific reason, as from a beginner's point of view this seems a bit of an unusual way to write a function in Java

Comment: if getTextBound returned Rect it would have to create a new Rect each time it was called, if you pass a Rect as a parameter you can allocate a new Rect only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method reuses an already existing instance of a `Rect` object and only changes its internal values, the second method creates a *new* instance every time it is called.

If you need to get the text bounds several times - for example if you replace the text in an animation - it would be a strain on the system to create new instances every frame and then garbage collect them, compared to reusing the same one instance.

The second one on the other hand is slightly more practical if you only need to get the bounds once, since you save one line of code.